# AWS CloudFormation keys not accepting special characters

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, concourse, concourse-pipeline, concourse-fly

I have noticed that AWS CloudFormation does not like special characters.

When I update a `key:value` pair in our `pipeline.yml` file with special char 
e.g. `PAR_FTP_PASS: ^XoN*H89Ie!rhpl!wan=Jcyo6mo`, I see the following error:

```
parameters[5] ParameterKey, ParameterValue or UsePreviousValue expected
```

I am able to update the value through the AWS CloudFormation UI.

It seems like the issue is to do with AWS CloudFOrmation parsing the yml file.

Is there a workaround with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

AWS Tags have some restrictions on what they can contain, see here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Using_Tags.html#tag-restrictions

A key note which can catch people out is: "*Although EC2 allows for any character in its tags, other services are more restrictive. The allowed characters across services are: letters, numbers, and spaces representable in UTF-8, and the following characters: + - = . _ : / @.*"

So I'd check if the service you are adding this onto can support that string.